# How to replace individual values in a row in pandas based on how frequently they appear?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Apologies in advance for how long this post is, and I'm extra sorry for the quality of the code, I'm fairly new to python

I'm currently working on a program to find consensus values from a table of values. For each column, I want to find isolate just the values that appear more than half the time (in terms of the original input sequences). So I have seven input sequences, each part of the sequence has five features, and I want to know which features appear in more than half of the input sequences. I've got a subset of the table I've produced so far below (referred to as all_res in code)

| Variable | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Size | small | large | medium |
| Hydro | hydrophobic | hydrophobic | neutral |
| Side | sulfur | aliphatic | hydroxyl |
| Size | small | small | medium |
| Hydro | hydrophilic | hydrophobic | neutral |
| Side | basic | aliphatic | hydroxyl |
| Size | small | very large | medium |
| Hydro | hydrophobic | hydrophobic | hydrophobic |
| Side | sulfur | aromatic | aromatic |

The plan was to replace any values that appear in less than half of sequences with an X, then delete any duplicates, so the ultimate goal would be the below table

| Variable | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Size | small | X | medium |
| Hydro | hydrophobic | hydrophobic | neutral |
| Side | sulfur | aliphatic | hydroxyl |

This is current code to get those X's in

```
for col in all_res:
    for i in all_res[col]:
       if all_res[col].value_counts()[i] <= len(input_sequences)/2:
          all_res.replace({col:i}, "X", inplace = True)
```

When I run this, however, it comes up with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Aliphatic'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh\OneDrive\Documents\PhD project\Thesis\Results\3. CKBP modelling project 260123 -\9. Combining data from analyses 1-6\CIWI design\ciwi.py", line 63, in <module>
    if all_res[col].value_counts()[i] <= len(input_sequences)/2:
  File "C:\Users\Josh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Aliphatic'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your dataframe to compute proportion and filter them. Finally, reshape again your dataframe to restore the original shape:

```
out = (df.melt('Variable', var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
         .groupby(['Variable', 'Column'])
         .agg('value_counts', normalize=True)
         .loc[lambda x: x > 0.5]
         .index.to_frame(index=False)
         .pivot_table(index='Variable', columns='Column', values='Value', 
                      aggfunc='first', fill_value='X')
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Variable            0            1         2
0    Hydro  hydrophobic  hydrophobic   neutral
1     Side       sulfur    aliphatic  hydroxyl
2     Size        small            X    medium
```